# "Mathematical state" with functional languages?

Tags: functional-programming

I've read some of the discussions here, as well as followed links to other explanations, but I'm still not able to understand the mathematical connection between "changing state" and "not changing state" as it pertains to our functional programming versus non-FP debate. As I understand, the basic argument goes back to the pure math definition of a function, whereby a function maps a domain member to only one range member. This is then compared to when a computer code function is given certain input, it will always produce the same output, i.e., not vary from use to use, i.e.i.e., the function's state, as in its domain to range mapping behavior, will not change.

Then it get foggy in my mind. Here's an example. Let's say I want to display closed block-like polygons on an x-y field. In GIS software I understand everything is stored as directed, closed graphs, i.e. a square is four vectors, their heads and ends connected. The raw data representation is just the individual Cartesian start and end points of each vector. And of course, there might be a function in the software that "processed" all these coordinate sets. Good. But what about representing each polygon in a mathematical way, e.g., a rectangle in the positive x, negative y quadrant might be:

```
Z = {(x,y) | 3 <= x <= 5, -2 <= y <= -1}
```

So we'd have many Z-like functions, each one expressing an individual polygon -- and not being a whiz with my matrix math, maybe these "functions" could then be represented as matrices . . . but I digress.

So with the usual raw vector-data method, I've got one function in my code that "changes state" as it processes each set of coordinates and then draws each polygon (and then deals with polygons changing), while the one-and-only-one-Z-like-function-per-polygon method would seem to hold to the "don't change state" rule exactly. Right? Or am I way off here? It seems like the old-fashioned, one-function-processing-raw-coordinate-data is not mutating the domain-range purity law either. I'm confused....

Part of my inspiration came from reading about a new idea of image processing where instead of slamming racks of pixels, each "frame" would be represented by one big function capable of "gnu-plotting" the whole image, edges, colors, gradients, etc. Is this germane? I guess I'm trying to fathom why I would want to represent, say, a street map of polygons (e.g. city blocks) one way or the other. I keep hearing functional language advocates dance around the idea that a mathematical function is pure and safe and good and ultimately Utopian, while the non-FP software function is some sort of sloppy kludge holding us back from Borg-like bliss.

But even more confusing is memory management vis-a-vis FP versus non-FP. What I keep hearing (e.g. parallel programming) is that FP isn't changing a "memory state" as much as, say, a C/C++ program does. Is this like the Google File System where literally everything is just sitting out there in a virtual memory pool, rather than being data moved in and out of databases and memory locations? Somehow all these things are related. Therefore, it seems like the perfect FP program is just one single function (possibly made up of many sub-functions) doing one single task -- although a quick glance at any elisp code seems to be a study of programming schizophrenia on this count.

Answer (score 3):

[Referential transparency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_%28computer_science%29) in programming (and mathematics, logic, etc.) is the principle that the meaning or value of an expression can be determined without needing any non-local context, and that the value of an expression doesn't change.  Code like

```
int x = 0;

int nextX() {
  return x++;
}
```

violates referential transparency in that `nextX()` will at one moment return `32`, and at the next invocation return `33`, and there is no way, based only on local analysis, *what* `nextX()` will return in any given location.  It is easy in many cases to turn a non-referentially transparent *procedure* into a referentially transparent *function* by adding an argument to the *procedure*.  For instance, in the example just given, the addition of a parameter `currentX`, makes `nextX` referentially transparent:

```
int nextX( int currentX ) {
  return currentX+1;
}
```

This does require, of course, that every time `nextX` is called, the previous value is available.

For procedures whose entire purpose is to modify state (e.g., the state of the screen), this doesn't make as much sense.  For instance, while we could write a method `print` which is referentially transparent in one sense:

```
int print( int x ) {
  printf( "%d", x );
  return x;
}
```

there's still a sort of problem in that the state of the system is modified.  Methods that ask about the state of the screen will have different results before and after a call to `print`, for instance.  To make these kinds of procedures referentially transparent, they can be augmented with an argument representing the state of the system.  For instance:

```
// print x to screen, and return the new screen that results
Screen print( int x, Screen screen ) {
  ...
}

// return the contents of screen
ScreenContents returnContentsOfScreen( Screen screen ) {
  ...
}
```

Now we have referential transparency, though at the expense of having to pass `Screen` objects around.  For instance:

```
Screen screen0 = getInitialScreen();
Screen screen1 = print( 2, screen0 );
Screen screen2 = print( 3, screen1 );
...
```

This probably feels like overkill for working with IO, since the intent is, after all, to modify some state (namely, the screen, or filesystem, or …).  Most programming languages, as a result, don't make IO methods referentially transparent.  Some, like Haskell, however, do.  Since doing it as just shown is rather cumbersome, these language will typically have some syntax to make things a bit more clean.  In Haskell, this is accomplished by `Monad`s and `do` notation (which is really out of scope for this answer).  If you're interested in how the `Monad` concept is used to achieve this, you might be interested in this article, [You Could Have Invented Monads! (And Maybe You Already Have.)](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html)

Comment: Yes, the whole "referential integrity" issue seems to be one aspect of the applications side of the functional purity question. But I still don't see the big picture. What does ref integrity buy me other than more oversight/control? Ultimately, FP isn't well explained -- at least to beginners like me -- other than by saying "you need it to do certain multi-core parallel stuff." The Google Big Data, CouchDB, et al. likewise: "does better job with big data." I guess I really need the math function to software function purity thing explained really good.

Comment: @user78162 In my opinion, some benefits of functional programming are more significant to theorists, and others to the programmers.  As a programmer, immutable state removes a whole class of potential bugs.  If you don't modify state, you don't have to worry about values getting modified while you're not looking.  For certain kinds of data structures, immutability guarantees that structure sharing is safe (e.g., lists [a c d] and [b c d] can share the same tail [c d]), and this can use less memory.  Reasoning about programs is easier, because methods can be analyzed independently.

Comment: "What does ref integrity buy me" -- my glib answer to people is "it makes sure that any bugs are *local* bugs, detectable through unit tests".

Comment: (continuing the previous thought:)  In real life, there are places where pure-functions are unwieldy (e.g. the function's result depends on not just its input, but also the local time zone, whether the output is a terminal or a file, and whether the current-user has admin privileges).  But using immutable data more often, even if not *always* feasible, is (imo) the single biggest win of FP, and the more you use it the more the answer "reasoning about programs is easier" sinks in.

Comment: @not-just-yeti +1 on both comments.  I hope it didn't sound like I was suggesting that referential transparency, functional programming, etc., are silver bullets.  I think functional programming techniques are useful as general guidelines, especially at the interface level.  If a function can be referentially transparent in its interface, that's the main benefit.  It doesn't matter so much if its _implementation_ modifies some local state;  that might be a more efficient way to implement an algorithm.

Comment: (continuing my previous thought):  A nice example of this is in implementing list-reversing functions.  I'm happy to iterate through a list, destructively pushing the elements into a new list, then returning the destructively reversed new list.  The implementation is efficient, and `reverse` is still referentially transparent (modulo list equality, not object equality).